# Show/hide second dropdown based on first dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show or hide certain selections in the second dropdown based on what is chosen in the first drop down. This is what I have in my function. Overall, I have an HTML table that I want populated with my JSON data based on the selections chosen. Right now, it will populate with just one drop down. I want to add a drop down to categorize them better.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {

        var selection = document.getElementById("data_options").value;

            document.getElementById("test_drop").value;

        var table = document.getElementById("data_values");

        $("#data_values tr").each(function () {
            var $selection = $('#data_options').val();

            $(this).find('td:not(:first-child)').each(function () {

            var $col = $(this).closest('table').find('th').eq($(this).index()).attr('id');
            var $row = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');

            $(this).text(orgs[$col][$row][$selection]);
        })
})
}
```

And then here are my two drop downs.

```
<body>
    <!-----first drop down---->
    <select id="test_drop">
        <option value="selection1">selection1</option>
        <option value="selection2">selection2</option>
        <option value="selection3">selection3</option>
    </select>

    <!-----second drop down---->
    <select id="data_options" onchange="myFunction()">
        <option value="authority">Authority</option>
        <option value="governance">Governance</option>
        <option value="Management">Management</option>
        <option value="use_cases">Use Cases</option>
        <option value="community">User Community</option>
        <option value="Definitions">Definitions</option>
        <option value="Periodicity">Periodicity</option>
        <option value="Start/End Criteria">Start/End Criteria</option>
        <option value="it_system">IT System/Database</option>
        <option value="Data Quality">Data Quality</option>
        <option value="Tailoring">Tailoring</option>
        <option value="Data Access">Data Access</option>
        <option value="Handling and Security">Handling and Security</option>
        <option value="Data Lifecycle">Data Lifecycle</option>
        <option value="Historical Archives">Historical Archives</option>
        <option value="Integration">Integration</option>
        <option value="Review/Approval">Review/Approval</option>
    </select>
```

So for example, if selection 1 is chosen in the first drop down, I want the first 6 selections for the second drop down. If selection 2 is chosen, I want the next 6 selections. And if selection 3 is chosen, I would like the last 5 selections shown. And then once the second selection is shown, my HTML table should populate with the JSON data. Here is a snippet of my JSON data.

```
var orgs = { 
    osd: { 
        acat_i: { 
            authority: "unknown", 
            governance: "unknown",
            management: "unknown",
            use_cases: "unknown",
            community: "unknown",
            definitions: "unknown",
            periodicity: "unknown",
            start_end: "unknown",
            it_system: "gems",
            data_quality: "unknown",
            tailoring: "unknown",
            data_access: "unknown",
            handling: "unknown",
            data_lifecycle: "unknown",
            historical: "unknown",
            integration: "unknown",
            review: "unknown"
        }, 
        acat_ii: { 
            authority: "unknown", 
            governance: "unknown",
            management: "unknown",
            use_cases: "unknown",
            community: "unknown",
            definitions: "unknown",
            periodicity: "unknown",
            start_end: "unknown",
            it_system: "unknown",
            data_quality: "unknown",
            tailoring: "unknown",
            data_access: "unknown",
            handling: "unknown",
            data_lifecycle: "unknown",
            historical: "unknown",
            integration: "unknown",
            review: "unknown" 
        },
```

If you could assist with how I can go about showing or hiding certain selections, that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: can you do a js fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to use vue and just add a v-model onto your select, and from there you can easily show things with a v-if.

(If you know how vue works that is)

Comment: I am not sure how vue works. Would you be able to provide an example?